# Hide borders of some columns in a table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, css-tables, bootstrap-table

I am building a bootstrap table: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ruciloxose/1/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table.table-border {
      border: 2px solid #E6E9ED;
    }
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid #E6E9ED;
      text-align: center
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-border table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">h12</th>
          <th colspan="4">h345</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>h1</th>
          <th>h2</th>
          <th>h3</th>
          <th>h4</th>
          <th>h5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>abc</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>efg</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hij</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to hide the borders between the columns `h1` and `h2`, between `h3` and `h4`, and between `h4` and `h5`. Does anyone know how to do it? A solution with JavaScript will be fine too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the borders to be removed, or made transparent, between each pair of odd and even `<td>` elements, then the following works:

```
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(even) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```css
table.table-border {
  border: 2px solid #E6E9ED;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #E6E9ED;
  text-align: center
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(even) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-border table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">h12</th>
        <th colspan="4">h345</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>h1</th>
        <th>h2</th>
        <th>h3</th>
        <th>h4</th>
        <th>h5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hij</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r5vuc8qk/).

This styles all the odd-numbered (`th:nth-child(odd)`) `<th>` elements within the second `<tr>` (`tr:nth-child(2)`) within the `<thead>` element with a `border-right-width` of `0` (effectively hiding it, although `border-right-color: transparent;` or `border-right-style: none` would achieve a very similar end-result).

The second selector does precisely the same thing, but selects the even-numbered children of the second `<tr>` of the `<thead>`.

In view of the comment below, clarifying the requirements:

> Sorry, I also want to delete the borders in Rows 3, 4, 5, between the columns h1 and h2, between h3 and h4, and between h4 and h5.

I'd suggest amending the selectors to the following:

```
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(odd),
tbody tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(even),
tbody tr td:nth-child(even) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```css
table.table-border {
  border: 2px solid #E6E9ED;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #E6E9ED;
  text-align: center
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(odd),
tbody td:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(even),
tbody td:nth-child(even) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-border table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">h12</th>
        <th colspan="4">h345</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>h1</th>
        <th>h2</th>
        <th>h3</th>
        <th>h4</th>
        <th>h5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hij</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r5vuc8qk/2).

This does exactly the same as above, but also selects the odd, and even, `<td>` children of the `tbody` and styles them appropriately along with the `<th>` elements of the second `<tr>` of the `<thead>`.

While all the requirements were in the question I appear to have studiously misread the question, for reasons unknown. With the prompt, again, in comments below:

> I also want to delete the border between h4 and h5

The approach here remains the same, but we use slightly more complex selectors by which to select the appropriate elements:

```
/* Selects the first <th> child of the second <tr>
   descendent of the <thead>, and also every first
   <td> child contained within the <tbody>: */
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:first-child,
tbody td:first-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

/* Selects the second <th> child of the second <tr>
   descendent of the <thead>, and also every second
   <td> child contained within the <tbody>: */
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2),
tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}

/* Selects every <th> element that follows the second
   <th> child element of the second <tr> of the <thead>
   using the general sibling ('~') combinator; and also
   every <td> that appears after the second <td> of the
   <tbody>: */
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2) ~ th,
tbody td:nth-child(2) ~ td {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
/* Because we (presumably) want the final <th> and <td>
   of each <tr> to retain its right-border, we here select
   every <th> element which is not the last-child of its
   parent which follows the second-child of the parent, and
   similarly for the <td> elements: */
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2) ~ th:not(:last-child),
tbody td:nth-child(2) ~ td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```

```css
table.table-border {
  border: 2px solid #E6E9ED;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #E6E9ED;
  text-align: center
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:first-child,
tbody td:first-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2),
tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2) ~ th,
tbody td:nth-child(2) ~ td {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2) ~ th:not(:last-child),
tbody td:nth-child(2) ~ td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-border table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">h12</th>
        <th colspan="4">h345</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>h1</th>
        <th>h2</th>
        <th>h3</th>
        <th>h4</th>
        <th>h5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>efg</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hij</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r5vuc8qk/3).

Comment: Sorry, I also want to delete the borders in Rows 3, 4, 5, between the columns h1 and h2, between h3 and h4, and between h4 and h5.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that part of the question; if you see the edited answer I think that should be what you're looking for?

Comment: I understand your idea... we are very close, I also want to delete the border between h4 and h5...

Comment: If you could take a look at the edit to check; I'm hoping I've finally got it somewhere close to your requirements? Sorry about my evident inability to read this morning, though... :-/

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I can only apologise for the multiple delays and my apparent inability to read today... >.<

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the border equal to 0px on both the left and right sides of the border you're getting rid of.

So for example:

```
<td style="border-right:0px;"> abc </td>
<td style="border-left:0px;"></td>
```

This should be the whole code below. Try it out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table.table-border {
      border: 2px solid #E6E9ED;
    }
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid #E6E9ED;
      text-align: center
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-border table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">h12</th>
          <th colspan="4">h345</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>h1</th>
          <th>h2</th>
          <th>h3</th>
          <th>h4</th>
          <th>h5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-right:0px;">abc</td><td style="border-left:0px;" > </td><td style="border-right:0px;"></td><td style="border-left:0px; border-right:0px;"></td><td style="border-left:0px;""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-right:0px;">efg</td><td style="border-left:0px;" > </td><td style="border-right:0px;"></td><td style="border-left:0px; border-right:0px;"></td><td style="border-left:0px;""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-right:0px;">hij</td><td style="border-left:0px;" > </td><td style="border-right:0px;"></td><td style="border-left:0px; border-right:0px;"></td><td style="border-left:0px;""></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works, but it is a pity that we have to make the style cell by cell rather than column by column...

Comment: Yes, very annoying. Maybe there is a faster way to do this? But I don't know it : /. Maybe if you just copy and paste the tables while hiding the border it will be faster? : /